# Spring boot with spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://otherhost/test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I developed a Spring boot application with MongoDB. While the MongoDB in the localhost, it works fine, but when the MongoDB is in different the server, I changed the setting in application.properties as

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://192.168.7.31/gcp
spring.data.mongodb.username=xxx
spring.data.mongodb.password=xxxxxxx
```

the application faileds as it still looks for the mongoDB in localhost

```
2017-01-04 11:47:46.161  INFO 15610 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Adding discovered server localhost:27017 to client view of cluster
2017-01-04 11:47:46.218  INFO 15610 --- [localhost:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
at  com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.2.2.jar:na]
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorR
```

Anyone can help to tell me how to set the parameters?

Comment: Can you show your config ?

Comment: Confirm that you have not hardcoded the url while creating the MongoClient. Kindly show us your code where you've created a MongoClient bean (if you've created one)

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? Please also check the hints in the documentation regarding the usage of `spring.data.mongodb.uri`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-connecting-to-mongodb